# Caused by: java.io.IOException: Tunnel failed, got: 400

Tags: java, http, proxy, request

I want to send a request with proxies but getting a error. How can I fix this error?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Tunnel failed, got: 400
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:586)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:119)
        at Main.main(Main.java:33)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Tunnel failed, got: 400
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainTunnelingConnection.lambda$connectAsync$2(PlainTunnelingConnection.java:97)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1150)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:614)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:653)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:482)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$DelegatingExecutor.execute(HttpClientImpl.java:157)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompletion.claim(CompletableFuture.java:572)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1Response$HeadersReader.handle(Http1Response.java:695)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1Response$HeadersReader.handle(Http1Response.java:621)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1Response$Receiver.accept(Http1Response.java:612)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1Response$HeadersReader.tryAsyncReceive(Http1Response.java:668)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http1AsyncReceiver.flush(Http1AsyncReceiver.java:233)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$LockingRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:205)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:149)
        at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:230)
xecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I think I found a solution but `java -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""` and `java -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""` commands not worked on Windows's terminal.

Here's my code. I removed inside of URI and BodyPublishers.ofString methods.

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .version(Version.HTTP_1_1)
            .uri(URI.create(""))
            .headers(httpHeaders)
            .method("POST", BodyPublishers.ofString(""))
            .build();

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .proxy(ProxySelector.of(new InetSocketAddress("88.198.24.108", 3128)))
            .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .build();

        HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = 
            httpClient.send(httpRequest, BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

Comment: Empty URI isn't valid in HTTP. Try new `URI.create("/")`

Comment: Does your code work without the proxy?

Comment: I removed it for security purpose. @MikeClark

Comment: Yes, it's working. @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Comment: Test the proxy in combination with the request using another framework like `curl` command-line or a GUI tool like `PostMan`. It may simply be that the proxy is refusing to forward the request you're sending it, in which case it's probably a problem with the proxy configuration, not your code.

Comment: The server might be not running. When I set to 176.9.63.62:3128 its working. @MikeClark